# what is the difference between Number ob(10,20) and Number ob=new Number(10,20) in java

Tags: java

A class 10th standard student asked me what is the difference between `Number ob(10,20)` and `Number ob=new Number(10,20)` in java?
in the first case `Number ob(10,20)` - Is it syntax error?

Comment: Yes: `Number ob(10,20)` to declare a variable is just not correct

Comment: Both will not compile and difference is error they will give. #1 makes no syntactical sense (what is that even supposed to mean?), #2 is invalid because Number is abstract class so (a) it can't be instantiated and (b) it doesn't have such constructor.

Comment: @Pshemo well... assuming `Number` is referring to `java.lang.Number` that is.

Comment: @Pshemo that's assuming the OP isn't talking about a custom Number class

Comment: Yes, my assumption is based on what we know from question, and since OP didn't specify that Number is custom class assuming it comes from `java.lang` seems most probable.

Comment: I guess he wanted to say C++, not java

Comment: just to be clear `Number ob(10, 20)` is not valid in Java; `Number ob = new Number(10, 20)` would be valid if there is an user class  `Number` with a constructor that accepts two numeric arguments - the standard `java.lang.Number` class does not have such constructor and is abstract, that is, you cannot create a direct instance of it.

Answer (score 1):

Both are incorrect:

`Number ob(10,20)`, syntax error

`Number ob = new Number(10,20)` syntax is correct but as `java.lang.Number` is abstract class so cannot be instantiated.

Source:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html

Answer (score 0):

Actually both are incorrect.

See below code snippet:

```
package Rough;

public class TestNumbers {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Number ob(10,20); // compilation error
        Number ob = new ob(10,20); // compilation error
        Number ob_2 = 5; // no error
        Number ob_3=new Number(10,20); // compilation error
    }

}
```

This shows that to initialize a Number class, you need to instantiate with actual value.
I advise to online compiler handy before asking https://www.jdoodle.com/online-java-compiler, all I am saying is it will enhance learning.

Welcome to SO.

[image]

Comment: You missed the case `Number ob=new Number(10,20)`

Comment: Added, though it is more about trying in actual IDE, understanding the concept ...